# Multiple submit buttons rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to make multiple submit buttons for a form, but I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=edit_individual
```

Found in:

```
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_user    
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

My controller page:

```
def edit_individual
  if User.find_by_id (params[:user_ids])
    if params[:Delete_multiple]
      @users = User.find(params[:user_ids])
      @users.each do |user|
        user.destroy
      end
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'All selected users were successfuly deleted'
    else
      @users = User.find(params[:user_ids])
    end
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'No users were selected for editing'
  end
end

def update_individual

  @users = User.update(params[:users].keys, params[:users].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
    if @users.empty?
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Users updated"
    else
    render :action => "edit_individual"
    end

end
```

My index page:

```
<%= form_tag edit_individual_users_path do %>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @q, :firstName, "First name" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @q, :lastName, "Last name" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @q, :registrationNumber, "Registration number" %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @q, :email, "Email" %></th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if (user.archive == false) %>
      <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id %></td>
      <td><%= user.firstName %></td>
      <td><%= user.lastName %></td>
      <td><%= user.registrationNumber %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'View', user, class: 'btn btn-info btn-mini', title: 'View users\'s information' %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user), class: 'btn btn-warning btn-mini', title: 'Edit users\'s information', method: 'get' %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', user, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-mini', title: 'Delete user', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><%= select_tag :field, options_for_select([["All Fields", ""], ["First name", "firstName"], ["Last name", "price"], ["Registration number", "registrationNumber"], ["Email", "email"]]) %></p>

<p><%= submit_tag "Edit checked", name: 'Edit_multiple' %></p>
<p><%= submit_tag "Delete checked", name: 'Delete_multiple', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete multiple users?' } %></p>
<% end %>
```

The edit_individual page:

```
<% form_tag update_individual_users_path, :method => :put do %>
  <% for product in @products %>
    <% fields_for "users[]", users do |f| %>
      <h2><%=h user.name %></h2>
      <%= render :partial "fields", :locals => { :f => f, :user => user } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

The routes file:

```
resources :users do
  get 'archive', on: :collection
  post 'edit_individual', on: :collection
  put 'update_individual', on: :collection
end
```

The delete part works fine. Also, the edit part actually edits the field, but displays that error (so it does not redirect back to the index page which makes it look bad).

Can anyone help me fix this? Spent a lot hours to have both `edit` and `delete` so it would be pretty bad if I had to delete the edit part.

EDIT 1: Also, If I am editing for example 3 users and click the submit button allowing only 2/3 to pass (due to validation), there is no error (I just get redirected back to `edit_individual.html` to finish the last user) and then if I have click submit again and everything passes, I get an error.

Comment: You can not create multiple submit button on a form as submit button will submit the form in a defined action. what you can do is add multiple button and handle the submit functionality through javascript.

Comment: You can do it, you just have to define a name for the button, and then use an "if statement" the way I use it in my controller (if params[:button_name].

Comment: @Meldanen: So, in effect, you will have only one submit button right. So, how can you say that you are using two submit buttons in a form? haSabyasachi Ghosh is right.

Comment: @RajeshCO No, they will indeed have two submit buttons rendered on the page in this case. The `params` hash will contain the `name` of the button that was clicked, which they check for in their controller. Only one of the two button names is submitted. Ryan Bates covered this in [episode 38](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form). Having said that, I've haven't seen / used this method in a very long time; it is typical of pre-Rails 3 systems I find, and usually not recommended.

Comment: @PaulRichter That is where I got the idea for the two buttons. Is there any other method you would suggest for doing this?
Also, why is it not recommended? I am new to ruby on rails so my knowledge on most things is poor (and I am always interested in learning new things).

Comment: @Meldanen Its mainly a convention issue. The "problem" is you would have one controller action performing two separate functions. It can be messy, and lead to a fat controller, which in the end reduces maintainability, clarity, and separation of concerns. As for an alternative, I'm not quite sure in your case as I'm not clear on how the "edit checked" concept should work. In general, maybe finding a way to separate the mass delete and mass edit. Otherwise, I'm not really sure without seeing the whole system.

Comment: @PaulRichter Most of the code (editing multiple entries) was taken by Ryan Bates in [episode 198](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually) if you are interested. 
The deleting part was my implementation of how I understood what I saw on that episode.
I'll see if I can find a better way of doing it, thank you again for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually managed to find what was wrong. 
The problem was with:

```
def update_individual

  @users = User.update(params[:users].keys, params[:users].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
  if @users.empty?
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Users updated"
  else
    render :action => "edit_individual"
  end

end
```

Instead of:

```
redirect_to :back
```

It should be:

```
redirect_to users_path
```

Or any other fixed path I suppose. Is there a way to keep "redirect_to :back", or do I have to create new methods for other views (within the same controller) that will use this?

Comment: Minor typo: `users_ath` should be `users_path` (I assume). As for your question, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "back functionality", but if you mean rendering / redirecting to the same page in the event of an error, the greater issue is that your routes and actions are not RESTful; so normally in this case you'd simply do something like `render :edit` by convention, but in your case you do indeed have to specify the route / action to render / redirect. In short, I think it is a "yes" to the second part of your question. Assuming I understand correctly.

Comment: Yeah I think you understood what I meant. 
It is getting a bit late (6 a.m.) so I apologise for my bad wording ^^
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

it should not be run because you has not any `params[:id]`

if you user before_filter then

```
before_filter: set_user except: [:update_individual, :edit_individual]

def set_user    
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and where you call `update_individual` in `edit_individual`